# How can I remove an attribute from all DOM elements with Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I want to remove the bgcolor attribute from all elements of a page I am scraping via Mojolicious.

My attempt has been the following:

```
$dom->all_contents->each(sub { $_->attr('bgcolor' => undef) });
```

but this seems not to work.

How do I do it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following uses [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) to delete the `bgcolor` attribute for every node:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do {local $/; <DATA>});

for my $node ($dom->find('*')->each) {
    delete $node->{bgcolor};
}

print $dom;

__DATA__
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello background color</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<table>
<tr><td bgcolor="blue">blue</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="green">green</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello background color</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<table>
<tr><td>blue</td></tr>
<tr><td>green</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Notes:

1. It's possible to use [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to limit the returned nodes to only those containing the specific attribute:

   ```
   for my $node ($dom->find('[bgcolor]')->each) {
   ```
2. One can also let Mojo handle the iteration like the following:

   ```
   $dom->find('*')->each(sub {
       delete $_->{bgcolor};
   });
   ```

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, the DOM attribute you're looking for isn't `bgcolor` but `background-color`, the css variety. `bgcolor` fell out of popularity a while ago, in favor of defining classes and using CSS to set the styling on an object (including its background color). Try `background-color` instead.

Comment: The *attribute* is `bgcolor`, the *CSS property* is `background-color`

Comment: Weeeelll I wish the pages I am scraping were neat and all - Borodin is right the attribute is bgcolor as in <td align="default" bgcolor="#F8F9FA>